# Eloquent create says column has no default value using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have an small API that i want to save into client mysql database.
For this purpose i'm using guzzle.

my controller:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $res = $http->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/address');
        $addresses = json_decode($res->getBody(),true);   
        // dd($addresses);
        Address::create($addresses);
    }
```

my model:

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    protected $fillable = ['Adresse', 'Mandant', 'Kategorie', 'Matchcode', 'Name1'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

my migration:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('Adresse')->primary();
        $table->smallInteger('Mandant');
        $table->smallInteger('Kategorie')->nullable();
        $table->string('Matchcode', 50);
        $table->string('Anrede', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('Name1', 50)->nullable();
   });
}
```

my api content:

```
[
{"Adresse":"1111","Mandant":"0","Kategorie":"0","Matchcode":"fgh8881","Anrede":"Firma","Name1":"Sample name"},{"Adresse":"2399","Mandant":"0","Kategorie":"0","Matchcode":"fgh8882","Anrede":"Firma","Name1":"Sample name 1"}
]
```

the problem is i get an error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Adresse' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `addresses` () values ())

when i limit the api content to one array i can save it without a problem. But if i have more arrays in my api i get this error.
`$fillable` property on the model is set.

Comment: change this line `$table->integer('Adresse')->primary();` to `$table->increments('Adresse');`

Comment: my primary key is not incrementing

Comment: then its your data type problem of primary column i guess

Comment: @MuhammadNauman while it's generally good practice, there's no rule that says the primary key must be autoincremeting

Comment: Yes @apokryfos , i should have thought about it.

Comment: try Anrede to include in $fillable

Comment: thank you i forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary key is not auto-incrementing the framework needs to know about it.

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'Adresse';
    protected $fillable = ['Adresse', 'Mandant', 'Kategorie', 'Matchcode', 'Name1'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Then to add all of the models:

```
public function index()
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $res = $http->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/address');
    $addresses = json_decode($res->getBody(),true);   
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
         Address::create($address);
    }
}
```

Comment: thats a goog point ! i don't get any error. but the problem is my database is empty.

Comment: Just realised you are trying to mass insert

Comment: yes. But with your help i got it. I changed the `Address::create()` to `Address::insert()` and added the `$incrementing` property

Answer (score 1):

Your API content is essentially 2 records. For mass inserting using eloquent you need to use `insert` not `create`

So either

1) have your api return 1 result

2) or change `Address::create($addresses);` to `Address::insert($addresses);`

Comment: i changed it, now i get an error: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: which solution, 2?

Comment: when i `dd($addresses)` i get this : `array:2 [▼
  0 => {#253 ▼
    +"Adresse": "1111"
    +"Mandant": "1"
    +"Kategorie": "0"
    +"Matchcode": "fgh8881"
    +"Anrede": "Firma"
    +"Name1": "Sample name"
  }
  1 => {#251 ▼
    +"Adresse": "2391"
    +"Mandant": "1"
    +"Kategorie": "0"
    +"Matchcode": "fgh8882"
    +"Anrede": "Firma"
    +"Name1": "Sample name 1"
  }
]`

Comment: and you decode like this? `$addresses = json_decode($res->getBody(),true);   `

Answer (score 0):

Set **Adresse** be auto-increment as well with primary key and your issue will be solved or If you do not want to set it to auto-increment then assign it to a default value.

Comment: i have chagend this now for the second column i get an error:`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Mandant' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `addresses` () values ())`

Comment: Actually when you upload multiple records some of them has missing field value that's why it happened. Please also set Mandant as nullable.

Comment: thats a problem cause i need i primary key that's not incrementing. i can't set the `$table->integer('Adresse')->primary();` to nullable or default value

Comment: You have to set `Mandant` as nullable not `Adresse`

Comment: i've chagend it (mandant to nullable) but the adresse is still not working because its a primary key

Comment: Your `Adresse` value has sometime empty value, now you need no explicitly check If `Adresse` coulmn has empty value then assign it some default value and insert it into DB

Comment: thats immposible because the source of the api is a mssql database. And there is Adresse a primary key. And also i'm just for purpose of tests creating an api with two records. In this two records i don't have any empty value

Answer (score 0):

check the table structure of `addresses` whether it have default value `NULL`  need to change default